# dispatch_async vs beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I need to implement a background process in an iOS app, that performs a job every 60 seconds. I know this can only be done while the app is in focus, but I do want this job to finish running in the background after the app is closed. I will use GCD to dispatch a timer that calls my job asynchronously every 60 seconds using either `dispatch_async` or `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

I am wondering which method is the best, or if they are essentially the same. Is it okay to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to execute a job even while the app is in the foreground? Or am I better off trying to cancel the job when the app state changes, and then restart the job as a background task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` doesn't run code on a background thread/queue. It tells the OS that you are going to continue doing work when your app is not active.

The two serve completely different purposes.

Comment: You are right, I will update my question to reflect that. So if I understand the documentation correctly I can call `- beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ` when the app state changes, and then call `endBackgroundTask:` when my job completes. I guess I had always assumed I needed to call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` when I started the job to be executed in the background.

Comment: They are still not the same, without `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` you won't get any extra time to finish your task in the background, `dispatch_async` or not, that does not matter.